# Fonts loading incorrectly on most browsers

Tags: fonts

The fonts of my website (http://www.mediaschip.nl) are suddenly messed up: the right font isn't loaded on most broswers. On Windows 8.1 they work proper on Chrome, but not on IE11 and Firefox.
On Mavericks they work proper on Safari, but not on Chrome and Firefox.

Until today they always worked proper. The site uses OpenSans fonts for all texts and some titles, and MontserratRegular for some titels.

I've tried quite some things and searched these forums/Google, but can't seem to find a solution.. I've disabled recent plugins, tried to fix css, emptied cache/history, tried other computers, but no results. In Firebug the font-family seems to get loaded, but is greyed out and nothing happens if I off that css line.

Please help! :(

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. The theme was referring to OpenSans/OpenSansRegular etc fonts. Changing those to Open Sans in multiple CSS files fixed it.